# Windows C compile rsync

Tags: c, rsync

I have problem with C compile to .exe.
I downloaded source code from https://www.itefix.net/dl/gpl-source/rsync-3.1.2.tar.gz and installed minGW. 
Then I try ./configure I get error: 
checking for socklen_t... no
checking for socklen_t equivalent... configure.sh: error: Cannot find a type to use in place of socklen_t 
I try with linux configure and its successful, but need rsync for windows .exe.

How to fix problem ?

Comment: MinGW is just a port of common POSIX tools into a Windows environment. It does not provide a POSIX system-call compatibility layer. Try Cygwin for that.

Comment: Or try MSYS2, which has a Cygwin-forked POSIX compatibility layer (msys-2.0.dll) and already has a package for rsync.

Answer (score 1):

A build of Rsync for Windows can be downloaded from here: https://www.itefix.net/content/cwrsync-free-edition .

Using this, you will not need to deal with the configuration scripts (which you would need to when compiling from source).

Comment: This link is no longer valid as itefix has decided to charge for downloads.